# ¿Qué significa el valor de error al usar Newton Rhapson?

Tags: python

no entiendo el problema de este ejercicio:

> hallar la raíz de x .exp(x)−π con un error menor a 0.1

Ya realicé mi codigo, y le puse un valor de 100 para evaluar, pero no entiendo que significa hallar con el error menor a 0.1 (este valor tambien ya puse en mi programa como variable fija)

Cuando veo la solucion de mi ejercicio, veo muchos valores que responden a ese valor como por ejemplo, (1.0736581948691901  -  9.246363443486731e-06 ) y
(1.0736581947961492 - 6.802994380361642e-11 ), cual debo considerar?

```
import numpy as np

def Funcion(x):
    f = x * np.exp(x) - np.pi
    return f

def D_Funcion(x):
    df =  np.exp(x) + np.exp(x) * x
    return df

def Newton_Raphson(x0):
    error =0.1
    tol=0.00000001
    while error >= tol:
        xf =x0 - Funcion(x0)/D_Funcion(x0)
        error = abs ((xf-x0)/xf)
        x0=xf
        print(xf, error)

Newton_Raphson(100)
```

Comment: Creo que te pide que pares de calcular cuando el error es menor o igual a 0.1. Y ahí parece que sigues el ciclo mientras error es mayor que tol ¿porqué usas esa variable?

Comment: Es que el ejercicio solo me dio esos datos :(

Comment: Veamos, ¿De donde sale tol? El error lo calculas bien pero no paras cuando te dice. Además si graficas la función verás que la raiz anda alrededor de 1, comienza con las iteraciones con un valor más bajo (1 por ejemplo)